# Kotlin Inheritance for Multiple Constructor Supertype

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to inherit the JFrame class. It says "This type has a constructor, and thus must be initialized here" so I can't write:

```
class MainFrame : JFrame
```

but:

```
class MainFrame() : JFrame()
```

Since I'm forced to declare a primary constructor I can't do this:

```
constructor(title: String) : super(title)
```

And I have to do this:

```
constructor(title: String) : this(title)
```

So I have to declare the primary constructor this way:

```
class MainFrame(title: String) : JFrame(title)
```

The problem is that this way every secondary constructor needs to call the primary constructor and then the supertype constructor of choice. If I have multiple supertype constructors I'm forced to delegate the process to that single supertype constructor that can be inconvenient if the supertype class has many constructors for many purposes.

There is some way to make a class with multiple constructors that call different supertype constructors?

**Edit:**

I can't remove the supertype constructor like this:

```
class MainFrame : JFrame
```

If I do I get this error:
*This type has a constructor, and thus must be initialized here*

**Solution:**

A constructor was missing but it can be a secondary constructor, so the error:

*This type has a constructor, and thus must be initialized here*

Can be solved by adding only a secondary constructor.

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary to use a primary constructor in your class definition. You can simply omit it, and then all your "secondary" constructors do not have to call a primary constructor, and can call the relevant super constructor instead.

```
class MainFrame: JFrame {
    constructor() : super() {

    }

    constructor(title: String) : super(title) {

    }
}
```

JFrame, does however follow the pattern of having an unofficial primary constructor in Java, so you could call through to this as your primary constructor and use the same defaults it uses:

```
class MainFrame(title: String = "", gc: GraphicsConfiguration? = null): JFrame(title, gc) {

}
```

Comment: The problem is that if I remove the primary constructor and the supertype constructor I get this error: "This type has a constructor, and thus must be initialized here"

Comment: Check carefully if your syntax deviates from mine above. Both examples I put above compile fine for me.

Comment: You are right, a constructor was missing but it can be a secondary constructor.